# Custom unwind segue class not work properly in Swift, why?

Tags: ios, swift

The following **unwind** segue class is not presenting the original VC to its original state and sliding from left-right -->| and reloading the data as expected after being segue right to a secondary VC.

The original VC is in a `UITabBarController`, the tabbar at the bottom is still showing but the rest of the screen is blank.

**Question: How do i unwind back reverting the initial segue to the secondary screen?**

```
class UnwindSegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {

override func perform(){

    let src = self.source
    let dst = self.destination


    src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, at: 0)
    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                   animations: {
                    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    },
                   completion: { finished in

                    src.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    })
}
}//end class
```

I have the following `SegueFromRight` class which works perfectly. But my corresponding unwind segue to that above is not working.

```
class SegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {

override func perform(){

    let dst = self.destination
    let src = self.source


    src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)

    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                   animations: {
                    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    },
                   completion: { finished in
                    src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
    })
}
}
```

Comment: You should try instead of `src.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)` to do `dst.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`

Comment: @Ladislav the change you suggested unwinds back to the original VC, but it doesn't do the transition animation (from Left to Right), any ideas?